# ¿Cómo mostrar los valores del metadato Field?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
show full fields from encuesta.cargos
```

La cual me devuelve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mediante PHP creo una tabla dinámica con la misma estructura de la imagen. Pero el problema surge en que no me muestra la columna **Field**, y no sé a que se pueda deber. Este es mi código:

```
print('
<div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered">
  <thead class="" style="background-color: #337ab7; color: #ffffff">
   <td></td><td></td>');
   $sql="show full columns from encuesta.cargos";
   $result=$link->query($sql);
   $campos = mysqli_num_fields($result); //regresa el # de campos del resultado especificado.
  //Pongo las cabeceras de los campos
  for ($j=1; $j<$campos; $j++){  
   $nombre_campo = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$j)->name;                
   echo "<td align='left'>".$nombre_campo."</td>";
  }
  echo "</thead>";
  //ecribo los datos de cada campo
  $result = $link->query($sql);                               
  for ($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($result);$i++){        
   echo "<tr>";               
   echo "<td><a href='".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."?editar&tabla=$tabla' title='Editar'><img src='../imagenes/editar.gif' border='0'></a></td>";
  echo "<td><a href='".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."?eliminar&tabla=$tabla' title='Borrar'><img src='../imagenes/eliminar.gif' border='0'></td>";
  $finfo = $result->fetch_row();
  for ($k=1; $k < count($finfo);  $k++) { 
   echo "<td>".$finfo[$k]."</td>";                  
  }   
  echo "</tr>";
 }
 print('</table>
 </div>
');
```

Esto es lo que obtengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como pueden ver me falta la columna del campo **Field**, que es la que no se porque no se visualiza.
Podría alguien echarle un ojo a mi código o decirme el por qué la columna Field, no visualiza con PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en tu for loop.  Tienes que empezar desde el indice 0 y no 1 asi:

```
for ($j=0; $j<$campos; $j++){  
   $nombre_campo = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$j)->name;                
   echo "<td align='left'>".$nombre_campo."</td>";
}
//.
//.
//.
for ($k=0; $k < count($finfo);  $k++) { 
   echo "<td>".$finfo[$k]."</td>";                  
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias colega, era un detalle, pero ya no lo veía, agradecido.